# Replace special strings from all columns of data.frame in R using dplyR

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My data frame looks like this

```
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,"0.05,",0.05,0.5,0.20,0.40,0.50,0.60)
time <- c(1,1,"1,",1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
ID <- c("1,","2,","3,",4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

test <- data.frame(value, time, ID)
test

   value time ID
1      0    1 1,
2    0.1    1 2,
3    0.2   1, 3,
4    0.4    1  4
5      0    2  1
6  0.05,    2  2
7   0.05    2  3
8    0.5    2  4
9    0.2    3  1
10   0.4    3  2
11   0.5    3  3
12   0.6    3  4
```

I want to replace the "," from all columns with "" but I am still getting an error
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :
no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"
I would like my data to look like this

```
  value time ID
1   0.00    1  1
2   0.10    1  2
3   0.20    1  3
4   0.40    1  4
5   0.00    2  1
6   0.05    2  2
7   0.05    2  3
8   0.50    2  4
9   0.20    3  1
10  0.40    3  2
11  0.50    3  3
12  0.60    3  4
```

***EDIT***

```
test %>% 
mutate_all(~gsub(",","",.))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest in this case might be to use `parse_number` from the `readr` package,
e.g. :

```r
apply(test, 2, readr::parse_number)
```

or in `dplyr` lingo:

```r
test %>% mutate_all(readr::parse_number)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple `base R`solution:

```
test <- sapply(test, function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", "", x)))
test
      value time ID
 [1,]  0.00    1  1
 [2,]  0.10    1  2
 [3,]  0.20    1  3
 [4,]  0.40    1  4
 [5,]  0.00    2  1
 [6,]  0.05    2  2
 [7,]  0.05    2  3
 [8,]  0.50    2  4
 [9,]  0.20    3  1
[10,]  0.40    3  2
[11,]  0.50    3  3
[12,]  0.60    3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
test %>%
  mutate_at(vars(value, time, ID), ~ gsub(".*?(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*).*", "\\1", .))
#    value time ID
# 1      0    1  1
# 2    0.1    1  2
# 3    0.2    1  3
# 4    0.4    1  4
# 5      0    2  1
# 6   0.05    2  2
# 7   0.05    2  3
# 8    0.5    2  4
# 9    0.2    3  1
# 10   0.4    3  2
# 11   0.5    3  3
# 12   0.6    3  4
```

The more we get into the "let's try to parse what could be a number", it can get crazy, including scientific notation. For that, `readr::parse_number` already suggested is likely a better candidate if you can accept one more package dependency.

However ... seeing this suggests that either the method of import has some mistakes in it, or however the data is *formed* has mistakes in it. While this patch works on those kinds of mistakes, it is far better to fix whichever error is causing this.

Comment: value still has a comma though

Comment: Thank you for your time and your detailed post r2evans, I highly appreciate

Comment: btw, one premise of my answer was to keep the data as a string, even if it looks like a number. Your expected output does suggest converting to `numeric` and `integer`, but you didn't state it. No problem either way, as all offered methods have pros/cons.